# How to write message onto a IBM WMQ using JMS API

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am a newbie to WMQ. I am trying to write a message onto a IBM MQ from eclipse IDE using jms api but I keep getting the below error even though I am setting WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT to 'WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_DEFAULT'. I am stuck with this now. Any help would be much appreciated.

ErrorMessage:

> ```
> Wrong MQ message attribute 'format': '        ' or 'MQHRF2  ' expected but was 'MQSTR   '
> ```

```
package com.java.queuebrowser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class JMS_Producer {

    private static String host = hostname;
    private static int port = 1414;
    private static String channel = "SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN";
    private static String user = null;
    private static String password = null;
    private static String queueManagerName = QMName; 
    private static String destinationName = QName;
    private static boolean isTopic = false;
    private static boolean clientTransport = false;
    private static  String filePath = null;


      // System exit status value (assume unset value to be 1)
      private static int status = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;

        try {
        // Create a connection factory
          JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
          JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

       // Set the properties
          cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT,"1");

          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host);
          cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
          if (clientTransport) {
              cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
          }
          else {
              cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
          }
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName);
          if (user != null) {
              cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
              cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
              cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            }

          cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_DEFAULT);
          // Create JMS objects
          connection = cf.createConnection();
          session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          if (isTopic) {
            destination = session.createTopic(destinationName);
          }
          else {
            destination = session.createQueue("queue://" + queueManagerName + "/" + destinationName + "?persistence=2&CCSID=1208&targetClient=0");
          }
          producer = session.createProducer(destination);



          // Start the connection
          connection.start();
          String line;
          filePath = "C:\\Users\\rraghuna\\Desktop\\test.xml"; 
          FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi, "UTF-8"));
          StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

          do {
            line = in.readLine();
            if (line!=null){
              if(line.trim().length()==0){
                break;
              }
               s = s.append(line);              
              }
            }  while (line != null); 
          System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + s);
          TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test");     
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT,"1");
          message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY, WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_JMS);
          message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_DEFAULT);
          message.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
          message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT,WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);
          message.setStringProperty("WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY", "WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ");

          // And, send the message
          producer.send(message);

          fi.close(); 
          recordSuccess();
        }
        catch (JMSException | IOException jmsex) {
          recordFailure(jmsex);
        }
        finally {
          if (producer != null) {
            try {
              producer.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException jmsex) {
              System.out.println("Producer could not be closed.");
              recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
          }

          if (session != null) {
            try {
              session.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException jmsex) {
              System.out.println("Session could not be closed.");
              recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
          }

          if (connection != null) {
            try {
              connection.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException jmsex) {
              System.out.println("Connection could not be closed.");
              recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
          }
        }
        System.exit(status);
        return;
      } // end main()

      /**
       * Process a JMSException and any associated inner exceptions.
       *
       * @param jmsex
       */
      private static void processJMSException(JMSException jmsex) {
        System.out.println(jmsex);
        Throwable innerException = jmsex.getLinkedException();
        if (innerException != null) {
          System.out.println("Inner exception(s):");
        }
        while (innerException != null) {
          System.out.println(innerException);
          innerException = innerException.getCause();
        }
        return;
      }

      /**
       * Record this run as successful.
       */
      private static void recordSuccess() {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        status = 0;
        return;
      }

      /**
       * Record this run as failure.
       *
       * @param ex
       */
      private static void recordFailure(Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
          if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
            processJMSException((JMSException) ex);
          }
          else {
            System.out.println(ex);
          }
        }
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
        status = -1;
        return;
      }

      /**
       * Display usage help.
       */
      private static void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("\nUsage:");
        System.out
            .println("JmsProducer -m queueManagerName -d destinationName [-h host -p port -l channel] [-u userid -w passWord]");
        return;
      }

    } // end class
```

Comment: Try removing the context and MQMD lines.  If you leave them you need to set the message format.

Comment: I commented out all the MQMD lines but still seeing the same error.

Comment: What about the CONTEXT line?

Comment: Hi JoshMc, I have removed "WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT" and all the other MQMD lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the error is not coming from your JMS application, but from the application that is consuming the messages, which seems to be a native MQ app.

If that is the case, you need to use targetClient=1 in your destination address.

And the WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT property is for the destination only, as far as I know, so you shouldn't set it on the connection factory, or the message.